# Xcode simulator closing when loading the main.py file

Tags: python, ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying to make an app for work while using Xcode ver. 14.3.1
I coded my basic app using Kivy on python 3 and everything worked so far!
But when I'm trying the simulator for an iPad Pro gen4 (or any iPad gen), my app on the simulator just close when it is trying to load my main.py (which is main.pyc in my project folder)
If you need anymore detail, please contact me!

Here is a photo of the log and my simulator: https://imgur.com/a/jEXJ3Uo

I tried to decode the main.pyc but Uncompyle6 doesn't seem to work on my Mac.
Could It be a Xcode version problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.